# Split a slice into N slices

Tags: go, split, slice

I'm a trying to implement a function that splits a slice of TCP ports into x others slices. Those slices will be sent to workers that will scan those ports, so x is set by the number of workers.

Here is the code :

```golang
// createJobs split portsToScan from a specified protocol into an equal number
// of jobs that will be returned.
func (t *Target) createJobs(proto string) ([]jobMsg, error) {
    // init jobs slice
    jobs := []jobMsg{}

    // check protocol accordance
    if _, ok := t.portsToScan[proto]; !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no such protocol %q in current protocol list", proto)
    }

    // if proto is ICMP, we do not need to scan ports
    if proto == "icmp" {
        return []jobMsg{
            jobMsg{ip: t.ip, protocol: proto},
        }, nil
    }

    step := (len(t.portsToScan[proto]) + t.workers - 1) / t.workers

    for i := 0; i < len(t.portsToScan[proto]); i += step {
        batch := t.portsToScan[proto][i:min(i+step, len(t.portsToScan[proto]))]

        jobs = append(jobs, jobMsg{
            ip:       t.ip,
            protocol: proto,
            ports:    batch,
        })
    }

    return jobs, nil
}
```

And here is the unit test corresponding :

```
func TestTarget_createJobs(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name         string
        pts          map[string][]string
        workersCount int
        wantErr      bool
    }{
        {
            name:         "5-1",
            pts:          map[string][]string{"tcp": []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}},
            workersCount: 1,
        },
        {
            name:         "5-2",
            pts:          map[string][]string{"tcp": []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}},
            workersCount: 2,
        },
        {
            name:         "5-3",
            pts:          map[string][]string{"tcp": []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}},
            workersCount: 3,
        },
        {
            name:         "5-4",
            pts:          map[string][]string{"tcp": []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}},
            workersCount: 4,
        },
        {
            name:         "5-5",
            pts:          map[string][]string{"tcp": []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}},
            workersCount: 5,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            tg := &Target{
                portsToScan: tt.pts,
                workers:     tt.workersCount,
            }
            got, err := tg.createJobs("tcp")
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("Target.createJobs() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
            if len(got) != tt.workersCount {
                t.Errorf("Target.createJobs() = %d, wanted %d jobs; joblist %v", len(got), tt.workersCount, got)
            }
        })
    }
}


func min(a, b int) int {
    if a <= b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

The output of the test give me this result :

```
--- FAIL: TestTarget_createJobs/5-4 (0.00s)
scan_test.go:309: Target.createJobs() = 3, wanted 4 jobs; joblist [{ 0  tcp [1 2]} { 0  tcp [3 4]} { 0  tcp [5]}]
```

Initial ports list is hold in `t.portsToScan[proto]` and the number of workers (so the number of slices I want to create) is set by `t.workers`.

At the end, `len(jobs)` must be equal to `t.workers` but I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm uses `step` as the size of batches:

```
step := (len(t.portsToScan[proto]) + t.workers - 1) / t.workers
```

This isn't the optimal size. For example if you have 4 ports to scan and 3 workers, this results in `step = 2`, which means you'll have only 2 jobs (`2+2=4`). But it would be better (more optimal) to have 3 batches (with sizes `2+1+1=4`).

So the size of batches should be

```
defSize := len(t.portsToScan[proto]) / t.workers
```

The problem with this is that if the length is not a multiple of `t.workers`, some of the last elements (ports) will not be assigned to any of the jobs. Using `defSize+1` for all jobs would be too many.

So the optimal solution is in the "middle": some jobs will have `defSize` ports to scan, and some will have `defSize+1`. How many must have `defSize+1`? As many as  missing if all would have `defSize`:

```
numBigger := len(t.portsToScan[proto]) - defSize*t.workers
```

Note that if there are less ports to scan than workers, the above calculation yields `defSize=0`, so some workers would get `0` ports to scan, and some would get `1`. That's OK, but you shouldn't add jobs with `0` ports to scan.

Using this distribution:

```
defSize := len(t.portsToScan[proto]) / t.workers
numBigger := len(t.portsToScan[proto]) - defSize*t.workers

size := defSize+1
for i, idx := 0, 0; i < t.workers; i++ {
    if i == numBigger {
        size--
        if size == 0 {
            break // 0 ports left to scan
        }
    }
    jobs = append(jobs, jobMsg{
        ip:       t.ip,
        protocol: proto,
        ports:    t.portsToScan[proto][idx : idx+size],
    })
    idx += size
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you clear and complete answer ! Following your way of thinking is really helpful !